# Approaches to overcome 255 characters limit of string variable in visual studio 2013 declarative workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, visual-studio-2013

We have one visual studio 2013 declarative workflow. In this workflow we are retrieving value of multiple line of text field & storing it within string variable.

Now, We are passing this string variable as email body within rest call (`_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail`) using `HttpSend` activity. But if variable contains more than 255 char then email is not going. And if variable contains less than 255 char then emails are going. Even `writeToHistory` also not working if variable contains more than 255 char.

How can I overcome this issue? Is there any work around? Please help. Thanks